# Vim: dynamic syntax-highlighting

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

I want to dynamically (i.e., depending on the content of the current file) adapt syntax highlighting. While this might be useful in general, my specific setting is as follows:

The kind of files I consider may contain (arbitrary many) blocks of the form `(VAR ...)`, where such "VAR-blocks" contain a space-separated list of identifiers that should be considered as variables (while identifiers that are not in a VAR-block are considered to be fixed function symbols or constants). Furthermore, there is already a file `trs.vim` that takes care of syntax highlighting for such files. In `trs.vim` a syntax group `trsKeyword` is declared. Now my goal is to highlight all variables using this group.

Consider the following example (lets call it `add.trs`):

```
(VAR x y)(RULES
  add(z, y) -> y  
  add(s(x), y) -> s(add(x, y))
)
```

When opening `add.trs` in *vim*, I want that `x` and `y` are printed as keywords (whereas for example `z` is not, despite having no arguments).

Answer (score 2):

I already achieved the desired result (but wanted to share it on SO). So here it is (the following snippets should be combined in a file `vars.vim`).

First I define a pattern that will recognize VAR-blocks:

```
" pattern that matches VAR-blocks of *.trs files
let varblock = '(VAR\s*\(.*\))'
```

Then I check the current file (maybe there is a better way than using `%` for that?) for VAR-blocks and ignore the case where no match was found.

```
" create list of variables from all VAR-blocks 
try
  silent exe "vimgrep /" . varblock . "/j %"
catch /^Vim\%((\a\+)\)\=:E480/ " no match
  " do nothing
endtry
```

The found matches are obtained by `getqfilst()`, which I copy. Then I replace every element in this list by the first subgroup that matched the `varblock` pattern (which will be a string containing space-separated identifiers). I join all such strings into a single one and then split it at spaces to get a list of identifiers:

```
let vars = split(join(map(copy(getqflist()), 'matchlist(v:val.text, varblock)[1]')))
```

Finally I create a pattern matching these identifiers and register it to the `trsKeyword` group:

```
" activate syntax highlighting for variables
exe "syn match trsKeyword \"\\<\\(" . join(vars, '\|') . "\\)\\>\""
" echo "variables: " . join(vars, ", ")
```

To make it work together with `trs.vim` I created the directory `~/.vim/syntax/trs` and put `trs.vim` as well as `vars.vim` inside. Then in my `~/.vimrc` I added

```
" TRS files
au BufNewFile,BufRead,BufWrite *.trs setf trs
```

which activates syntax highlighting for files ending with `.trs` (and also updates the list of variables whenever a buffer is saved).